# Are Groovlets deprecated?

Tags: groovy

There was a link to Grrovlet but when clicking on it it gives error 404 :

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets

linked from here :

https://kousenit.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/writing-json-output-from-a-groovlet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, codehaus closed down about a year ago

The documentation you're looking for is here:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/servlet-userguide.html